# Unable to use recorded mp3 as input to the google speech to text api..!

Tags: java, android, displaytag

I was working on an app which will allow is to record the voice on a call and display it in text form after ending the call.. 
But google speech to text api is not allowing me to give the recorded sound as input !! Can anyone please help me out ..

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about Google text to speech but:

Text to Speech is called synthesis. It plays the text types or provided using an inbuild speech engine. The ascent and phonetic used are provided by the engine.

Speech to text on the pother hand is called recognizer. it recognizes the phonetic sounds of the words in the speech and tells you which words may have been said.

From what you have written you probably need a recognizer and not a synthesizer.

Comment: Sorry bro !! It was the speech to text api itself which I used